# How to add " You save $xxx " in category / product listing page in Bigcommerce?

Tags: html, e-commerce, bigcommerce

We have option to add " You save $xxx.xx " text on product page in Bigcommerce using this variable %%GLOBAL_YouSave%%

Which show the special price and savings like this :- http://screencast.com/t/dUkulAqmIL

But do we have any similar variable for category page? I mean can we show something similar on category page?

so we can add similar text in category page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question a bit. As it stands, this is very hard to understand.

Comment: Hi @Ares Thank you for your response I just updated question, please review :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make %%GLOBAL_YouSave%% work on the CategoryProductsItem.html snippet and wasn't successful.

I have done variations of this for various MAP policies in jQuery. You can try this in the category page. Hope this helps:

```
$('.RetailPriceValue').each(function(){
var saveValue = ($(this).html().substring(1)) - ($(this).siblings('.SalePrice').html().substring(1));
saveValue = saveValue.toFixed(2);
$(this).siblings('.SalePrice').append( "<br /><b> You Save: $" + saveValue + "</b>" )
});
```